# Showing both the analytical and numerical versions of a matrix

Tags: hold

I have found that the Defer function, among others such as HoldForm or Inactive, seems to be the key to something I want to do, but I have been unable to figure out. If I calculate the value of a variable and then print it using Defer, it correctly shows me the name of the variable. Doing so in a matrix however simply prints out the name of the matrix rather than the names of the variables within that matrix. I understand why this is the case, but I am unable to figure out how to apply this Defer to the elements of the matrix rather than to the matrix as a whole.

As an example:

```
a1 = 42;
mat = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}};
Print[Defer[MatrixForm[mat]]]
Print["***"]
Print[MatrixForm[mat]]
```

This currently prints:

```
mat
***
42  a2
b1  b2
```

What I would like is:

```
a1  a2
b1  b2
***
42  a2
b1  b2
```

This is a minimal example. In my case, I have several matrices, which are not necessarily 2x2, for which I would like to show both the analytical and numerical versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
a1 = 42;
mat = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}};
```

Then mat has `42` already in there. So too late.  I think you probably want

```
a1 = 42;
mat = HoldForm[MatrixForm@{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}];
Row[{mat, " = ", ReleaseHold@mat}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is important to note that after `ReleaseHold@mat` the `MatrixForm` wrapper is still there. So if you want to actually use `mat` for computation you need to do

```
mat = Flatten[List @@ ReleaseHold[mat], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now you can use `mat` in rest of code as it now has no wrapper and no Hold on it.

**Update**

Better ways than what I did (less typing) to remove `MatrixForm` and the `Hold` heads from mat is as suggested below by Somos. These are

```
mat = First@ReleaseHold[mat]
```

or

```
mat = Identity @@ ReleaseHold[mat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice, and I am grateful for your edits which make it much more condensed! I am not sure I understand the @ syntax, so if you are able to add an explanation as to how that works I would really appreaciate it.

Comment: @sg1234  the `@` is just the same as `[...]` so instead of writing `foo[4]` you could, if you want, write `f@4`  it saves one key stroke, that is all. If you are lazy, you'll find yourself using `@` more.

Comment: thanks, I've reverted to brackets since I find that easier to read :) but I will keep that in mind and will no doubt move to @ once I am more comfortable with this language...

Comment: I suggest `Identity@@ReleaseHold[mat]` instead.

Comment: @Somos that is nice. I did not know this trick. Thanks.,

Comment: You can use `First@ReleaseHold[mat]` also.

Comment: @Somos Yes, this is even simpler. Less typing. no op have many choices to pick from !

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica is a very rich symbolic language, and there are many ways to achieve the same result. However, given your description of the problem and my feeling that you are a novice in Mathematica, I would not immediately go to `Defer` or `HoldForm`, which are somehow more sophisticated and advanced functions, but would use a more common/idiomiatic approach with rules and [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html). This keeps the symbolic form of your matrix and its numerical values completely separated, combining them only when you explicitly want to do so.

```
mat = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}};

(* The following can come from some other function 
   that calculates values, e.g. vals = solveProblem[...]; *)
vals = {a1 -> 42, a2 -> 43, b2 -> -5};

Print[MatrixForm[mat]]
Print["***"]
Print[MatrixForm[mat /. vals]]
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct in your assessment of my Mathematica knowledge, and I like this answer a lot as well. I might end up using this version instead... But even if I don't (after all, my code now works and I am happy to move on...), I will definitely keep this way of doing things in mind for other cases, so thank you for taking the time to add this asnwer despite the other one having already been accepted!

Comment: PS: actually, I really much prefer this way of doing things, the code is much more readable... My minimal example was perhaps too minimal, but using the matrix after via the "Flatten[List @@ ReleaseHold[mat], 1]" command obscures things a bit... Not too sure what (n)etiquette says regarding changing the accepted answer? I feel both are really good and the one to choose could depend on one's use case, but in my case I will be using this one for my situation.